# Strategy on how to share parameters between an object and one of its members

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I would like to ask what is the "best" way to share a parameter between an object and one of its members. I try to explain better my problem: I have  a class A which needs a specific a parameter to be defined:

```
class A
{
public:
  A(int);
  ~A();
private:
  int ParameterA;
  ...
}
```

Also I have a second class B which contains an object of class A as its member and needs another parameter to be defined:

```
class B
{
public:
  B(int);
  ~B();
private:
  A  MemberA;
  int ParameterB;
  ...
}
```

Now my question is: if ParameterA and ParameterB are always equal, what is the "best" (clean) strategy to use?

I thought of three possibility

1. First option is to have two copies of the same value saved with
   different names as in the code above. This seems to me quite
   "dangerous", it would force me to always check that the two values
   are equals.
2. Declare public the ParameterA, so class B can access it
3. Define a get function so class B can access ParameterA using the get function

Is there any other (better/standard) approach to deal with this case? What method should I follow?

Comment: ever heard of the keyword friend ? see this link http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

Comment: What is the demand? does class B must have another, different parameter, that will be always equal to the one in 'MemberA', or you just need the option to access the value of 'MemberA' from B?

Comment: Well if they are aways equal.. What is your main concern? Do you think you have to protect this case. Do you have to make sure that this relation will never change? For example if this value is kind of a ID and both objects are created in relation to another you could initialize them with a static const value.

Comment: This is a little bit too abstract to answer precisely. It seems that between the three possibilities, the third one is the best one. If your requirements were clearer, maybe some other alternatives might appear to better match the problem.

Comment: @Alex: Yes I want to make sure that this relation will never change, but I cannot use a const value since it should be possible to change ParameterA (and ParameterB) during the execution.

Comment: @user265732: It is not a concern, may question is if there is a standard approach to ensure that ParameterA and ParameterB are always equal to each other, even if they can change during the program execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare ParameterA as a reference, and intialize it to reference ParameterB.

```
class A
{
public:
  A(int& val) : ParameterA(val) {}
  ~A(){}

private:
  int& ParameterA;
};

class B
{
public:
  B(int val) : ParameterB(val), MemberA(ParameterB) {}
 ~B(){}

private:
  int ParameterB;
  A  MemberA;
};
```

Comment: Nice Westbrook I like it! But i have a corollary question: using your solution, would it will be possible to create "independet" objects of class A, i mean object of class A which are not members of any other object?

Comment: Nice. 'MemberA(ParameterB)' will do it to, as you call A's Copy Constructor for no reason.

Comment: This is a valid solution but it does have its drawbacks. Reference member variables restrict what you can do with your classes (e.g they are not assignable) and the life of `A` and `B` are now dependent on the life of an external parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition about the danger of having two variables always holding the same value is right: this is at the very least a code smell and should be avoided.

The straightforward solution is inheritance:

```
class A {
    public:
        A(int a) : parameterA(a) {}
    protected:
        int parameterA;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        B(int a) : A(a) {}
};
```

Of course, it depends on the context whether this solution is advisable, but it should always be the first to be evaluated.

Comment: I assume OP had a good reason for wanting `B` to contain an `A`.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Well, it *does* contain an `A` - via inheritance.

Comment: No, in your design `B` _is-an_ `A`, that's very different. You might be right, maybe OP can change their design from composition to inheritance.

Comment: Thanks @cmaster for my program I cannot derive B from A but it is interesting

Comment: @ChrisDrew *Logically* a `B` is an `A`, that is true. But what happens in memory? There is an object of class `B` that contains a subobject of class `A` that happens to be the first object within `B`. I. e. exactly the same memory layout as if you had defined `class B { public: A myBase; };`. The only difference is in the syntax that is used to access the `A` subobject.

Answer (score 1):

The "best" way will probably depend on how `A` and `B` are used.

Of your options, I would avoid 1 and 2 if you can but I think 3 might be a reasonable option unless the parameter is really not something you want to expose. If you want to keep the parameter private you could make `B` a friend of `A`.

Another option is to take the ownership of the parameter away from `A`. You could define the parameter outside the class (maybe inside another class) and pass a reference or pointer into `B` and `A`.

A more flexible approach might be to use a shared pointer but you might not need that flexibility in practice. By using a `shared_ptr` you do not restrict what you can do with your classes like references would and it doesn't tie the lifetime of `A` or `B` to the lifetime of an external object. And can easily create a self contained `A` on its own if you want:

```
#include <memory>

using SharedInt = std::shared_ptr<int>;

class A {
public:
  A(SharedInt parameter) : parameter_(parameter) {}
private:
  SharedInt parameter_;
};

class B {
public:
  B(SharedInt parameter) : a_(parameter), parameter_(parameter) {} 
private:
  A  a_;
  SharedInt parameter_;
};  

int main() {
  auto b = B(std::make_shared<int>(3));
  auto a = A(std::make_shared<int>(7));
}
```

But I might be tempted to go for a more restrictive design first and only move to shared pointers if needed.